# Javascript/Angular 5 - clicking multiple buttons only affects one

Tags: javascript, typescript, onclick, angular5, getelementbyid

I have a grid of 4 buttons and once one of them is clicked it will call a function called `doSearch` which checks which button was clicked and based on that assigns a string to the `last_search` value.

However, when I click any of the four buttons, I always seem to only press the `edm` button and reads 'i am edm' to console.

Could anyone explain why that is?

html

```
<!-- grid for music -->
<ng-container *ngIf="show" >
  <div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col">
      <button mat-button id="edm-btn" type="submit" (click)="doSearch($event)">EDM</button>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col">
      <button mat-button id="house-btn" type="submit" (click)="doSearch($event)">House</button>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col">
      <button mat-button id="pop-btn" type="submit" (click)="doSearch($event)">Pop</button>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col">
      <button mat-button id="dubstep-btn" type="submit" (click)="doSearch($event)">Dubstep</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

function code

```
doSearch(event): void {

    if (document.getElementById('edm-btn')) {
      this.last_search = 'edm';
      console.log('i am edm');
    } else if (document.getElementById('house-btn')) {
      this.last_search = 'house';
      console.log('i am house');
    } else if (document.getElementById('pop-btn')) {
      this.last_search = 'pop';
      console.log('i am pop');
    } else if (document.getElementById('dubstep-btn')) {
      this.last_search = 'dubstep';
      console.log('i am dubstep');
    }
}
```

---

FIX:

instead of passing the `id` of the button, I decided to pass a string directly into the function call of `doSearch`

html

```
<!-- grid for music -->
<ng-container *ngIf="show" >
  <div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col">
      <button mat-button id="edm-btn" type="submit" (click)="doSearch('edm')">EDM</button>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col">
      <button mat-button id="house-btn" type="submit" (click)="doSearch('house')">House</button>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col">
      <button mat-button id="pop-btn" type="submit" (click)="doSearch('pop')">Pop</button>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col">
      <button mat-button id="dubstep-btn" type="submit" (click)="doSearch('dubstep')">Dubstep</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

function

```
doSearch(category): void {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(category, null, 2));
    if (category === 'edm') {
      this.last_search = 'edm';
      console.log('i am edm');
    } else if (category === 'house') {
      this.last_search = 'house';
      console.log('i am house');
    } else if (category === 'pop') {
      this.last_search = 'pop';
      console.log('i am pop');
    } else if (category === 'dubstep') {
      this.last_search = 'dubstep';
      console.log('i am dubstep');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you read an id of html element and passing event instead of directly passing the string values to the function?

Comment: Because I am stupid lol. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because no matter what event you pass, your 1st condition is always true. You are passing an event, not the actual data, as well as checking if an element exists even if it already is.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need here if and else, it's enough:

```
public doSearch(category: string) { 
  this.last_search = category;
}
```